# How to avoid ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I updated my rails app to Rails 4.1 and started getting ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest exception. I found bing bots actively crawl my dynamically generated javascript file.

I think it's correct that rails raises this exception since javascript is called directly, but my log is filled up with this exception.

Is there a way to avoid bots raising this exception without turning off csrf protection?

My Controller looks like this.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def add
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'add' }
      format.html { redirect_to list_path(@list) }
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to `J-H`'s answer, and assuming you need some help with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you should know that every host uses a [CORS policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to determine who can (and can't) access their server directly

Your error is basically because your server's CORS policy is still defaulted to "denying" every direct XHR access. The way around this is to determine the [endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) on your server which will be available for external resources

It happens the best way to do this is to use the [`rack-cors` gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), as recommended by `J-H` :)

Comment: In my case also it is happening due to google bot, bing bot and pinterest. But why all bot are trying to access js files directly? And as per above gem it will help to allow. But what if I don't want to allow?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm in the same place as Rahul here: I don't want these bots to access these js files directly. If they crawl a page and that page loads JS, that's not a CORS issue (that would be the same as you visiting the page in the browser and it loading the associated JS files). It's when the bots try to directly request the JS files. Is there a good way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try something like the Rack-Cors gem: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors